Why cannot I not maintain the timezone information with matplotlib mdates
I need to plot some patches which requires me to use the matplotlib mdate module (ideally) to have control over the tick markers. I have used mdates before and I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get back the EDT times I expect (without using a weirdo timezone). Given the code below, I would expect to see that the converted values give me back what I started with.
NOTES:

Time on my machine is: Fri Nov  1 10:59:04 AM EDT 2024
mpl.rcParams['timezone'] = 'UTC'

See the code:
print(f"Start Date: {startDt} TYPE: {type(startDt)}")
print(f"End Date: {endDt} TYPE: {type(endDt)}")
startDt_utc = startDt.tz_convert('UTC')
endDt_utc = endDt.tz_convert('UTC')
print(f'RAW :: start: {startDt:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}, end: {endDt:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}')
print(f'UTC :: start: {startDt_utc:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}, end: {endDt_utc:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}')
print(f'RAW mdates :: start: {mdates.date2num(startDt)}, end: {mdates.date2num(endDt)}')
print(f'UTC mdates :: start: {mdates.date2num(startDt_utc)}, end: {mdates.date2num(endDt_utc)}')
s,e = mdates.date2num(startDt),mdates.date2num(endDt)
sutc,eutc = mdates.date2num(startDt_utc),mdates.date2num(endDt_utc)
newS,newE = mdates.num2date(s,tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), mdates.num2date(e,tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
newSutc,newEutc = mdates.num2date(sutc,tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), mdates.num2date(eutc,tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(f'RAW cvtr :: start: {newS:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}, end: {newE:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}')
print(f'UTC cvtr :: start: {newSutc:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}, end: {newEutc:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}')


#####
newS,newE = mdates.num2date(s,tz=pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+8')), mdates.num2date(e,tz=pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+8'))
print(f'cvtr Random :: start: {newS:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}, end: {newE:%b-%d:: %I:%M %p %Z}')

Produces this output:
Start Date: 2024-10-31 13:52:01-04:00 TYPE: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
End Date: 2024-11-01 10:51:01-04:00 TYPE: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
RAW :: start: Oct-31:: 01:52 PM UTC-04:00, end: Nov-01:: 10:51 AM UTC-04:00
UTC :: start: Oct-31:: 05:52 PM UTC, end: Nov-01:: 02:51 PM UTC
RAW mdates :: start: 20027.744456018518, end: 20028.618761574075
UTC mdates :: start: 20027.744456018518, end: 20028.618761574075
RAW cvtr :: start: Oct-31:: 05:52 PM EDT, end: Nov-01:: 02:51 PM EDT
UTC cvtr :: start: Oct-31:: 05:52 PM EDT, end: Nov-01:: 02:51 PM EDT
cvtr Random :: start: Oct-31:: 01:52 PM -08, end: Nov-01:: 10:51 AM -08

I'm expecting that the line "RAW cvtr :: ..." should be the same as "RAW ::" above. However I lose 4 hours. I've tried maintaining UTC inputs (as well as specific np.datetime64 types not shown) and no luck. Seems like it doesn't really care to convert to UTC correctly nor use the tzinfo correctly.
Please advise!
I am able to convert a single value, but I don't understand why the mdates can't seem to understand how to handle tzinfo
CODE
someTime = dfDeviceStatus['time'][0]
print(f"INIT TIME: {someTime:'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'}")
utc_dt = someTime.tz_convert('UTC')
print(f"CONVERT TO UTC: {utc_dt:'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'}")
mplDate = mdates.date2num(utc_dt)
print(f"CONVERT TO mdates num: {mplDate}")
newDT = mdates.num2date(mplDate)
print(f"CONVERT TO mdates date: {newDT:'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'}")
tzInfo = timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)
print(f"TZINFO (from inital known tzinfo): {tzInfo}")
offset = dfDeviceStatus['time'][0].to_pydatetime() - newDT
print(f"offset {offset}")
offDt = newDT + offset + tzInfo
print(f"FINAL DT {offDt:'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'}")

OUT
INIT TIME: '2024-10-31T13:52:01-0400'
CONVERT TO UTC: '2024-10-31T17:52:01+0000'
CONVERT TO mdates num: 20027.744456018518
CONVERT TO mdates date: '2024-10-31T21:52:01+0000'
TZINFO (from inital known tzinfo): -1 day, 20:00:00
offset -1 day, 20:00:00
FINAL DT '2024-10-31T13:52:01+0000'


Pandas is not matplotlib. Date2num is meant to work on datetime64 or raw datetime objects.  It is not meant to work on pandas timestamps.

While not shown, I have tried datetime64 and raw datetime objects but I'm still having consistent issues with mdates converting in unexpected ways. The optimal strategy seems to be convert to UTC before passing to mdates.

the issue appears to be around how date2num and num2date handles the datetime conversions. For those stuck (like me) I have found that manually converting ahead of time seems to be the best option. See code and output below.
CODE
someTime = dfDeviceStatus['time'][0]
print(f"INIT TIME: {someTime:'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'}")
offset = someTime.utcoffset().total_seconds()
convertTime = someTime + timedelta(seconds=offset)
print(f"CONVRT TIME {convertTime}")
mplDate = mdates.date2num(convertTime)
print(f"CONVERT TO mdates num: {mplDate}")
newDT = mdates.num2date(mplDate,tz="US/Eastern")
print(f"CONVERT TO mdates date: {newDT:'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'}")

OUT:
INIT TIME: '2024-10-31T13:52:01-0400'
CONVRT TIME 2024-10-31 09:52:01-04:00
CONVERT TO mdates num: 20027.577789351853
CONVERT TO mdates date: '2024-10-31T13:52:01-0400'

I hope someone can provide a better answer, but manually converting ahead of time seems to work for now
